# Microsoft Access - Flag line item on report if checklist not complete

Tags: ms-access, report

I've been a reader on this site for years but today is the first day I have to ask my own question. Apologies if my formatting could be better.

I'm creating a tracking system for client applications and need to create a small notification indicating if the end user analyst is missing any checklist items regarding a given contact on the application.

My current set up involves a table with the contact information (RecordID, ParentID, FirstName, LastName, Email, Phone), a table with the analyst checklist (RecordID, ParentID, UniqueEmail, PhoneNumPresent, AddressIsResidential) and a form that contains a subreport that queries the correct contact names for the client.

The subreport is a list of record ID's, which are hidden from the end user but present to make the pop up checklist function, and the contact names. Ideally if any item is missing from the analyst checklist a small caution icon will pop up next to the contact name in the report and stay there until the checklist is completed. I can make this work in other parts of the form, for different checklists, but not inside of a report.

No matter which approach I try, the script changes the visibility of the icon on EVERY line item instead of just the line item in question. I have tried the approach below, as well as putting similar code into Detail_Format (Event doesn't trigger when I need it to), and storing the flag as a Yes/No Boolean on the same table that the report queries (the report does not update automatically and when it does update I run into the same issue).

```
Private Sub ContactFirstLastName_Click()

    'Open Checklist for a given contact
    CurrentContact = Me.ID
    CurrentContactName = Me.ContactFirstLastName.Value
    DoCmd.OpenForm "ContactsChecklistForm", , , , , acDialog
    
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    SetRecord rs, "DocGatheringContacts", , Me.ID, "ID"
    
    Dim UniqueEmail As Boolean
    Dim PhoneNumPresent As Boolean
    Dim DOBPresent As Boolean
    Dim AddressResidential As Boolean
    
    UniqueEmail = rs.Fields("UniqueEmail")
    PhoneNumPresent = rs.Fields("PhoneNumPresent")
    DOBPresent = rs.Fields("DOBPresent")
    AddressResidential = rs.Fields("AddressResidential")
    
    If UniqueEmail And PhoneNumPresent And DOBPresent And AddressResidential Then
        Me.ContactWarning.Visible = False
    Else
        Me.ContactWarning.Visible = True
    End If
    
End Sub
```

My confusion stems from the fact that in the above code Me.ID and Me.ContactFirstLastName.Value both accurately reflect the name that I click on, but after the analyst checklist ("ContactsChecklistForm") is closed Me.ContactWarning seems to affect all instances of "ContactWarning" instead of only the line instance I am clicking. From what I understand from Microsoft's documentation "Me" should be referring to the entire report the entire time, but it doesn't appear to be until Me.ContactWarning is used.

Any thoughts on why that may be happening or another approach I can take to achieve the desired effect?

Comment: Forgot to mention, SetRecord is a custom function that makes it easier to query records within VBA. It seems to function perfectly so I doubt it will directly relate to any solution.

Comment: Are you sure you mean to say "subreport" here and not "subform"?  While it is possible to embed a report in a form, it sounds like you're describing a form for clients, then a subform within that form for client contacts, and a popup form with a checklist in it.  Perhaps your description could be a bit clearer?

Comment: Setting properties of a control with VBA will show the same setting for ALL records because there is only the one control - unless code is in Format or Print event and report is opened in PrintPreview or direct to printer. Report embedded on form is in ReportView so Format and Print events will not trigger. Should use a textbox as 'flag' indicator and Conditional Formatting to set colors. Conditional Formatting can call a VBA function.

Comment: @June7, Using a textbox and conditional formatting to trigger my function sounds extremely promising, I will give that a shot and update on my results. I am still confused regarding how my above code can get the proper ID and Contact Name when I click, but setting a property doesn't work. Having only one control makes sense with what I understand about reports, but how does the system get the correct Me.ID and Me.ContactFirstLastName from a report with multiple records?

Comment: Thanks @deluxeinformation, you're certainly right, my description could have been a bit clearer. I wrote this while at the end of my wits with the issue. The current set up is a form for a given client which contains an embedded report for client contacts with a little bit of vba to open a popup form with a checklist in it. Very similar to what you've described, with the caveat that the issue I am facing is within an embedded report, rather than a subform.

Comment: @June7 Solution posted below, thank you very much for your insight!

Comment: Code pulls values from whatever record has focus.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up taking a different approach to the problem. Initially I was attmepting to run my flagging script as part of the ContactFistLastName_click event so that it would trigger whenever the checklist was viewed, however I have found it more effective to run my flagging script as part of the checklist okay_click event so that it only triggers when the checklist is updated.

Drawing on the advice from June7 above, I switched from an image control to a textbox control that is linked to a field on the table that the report queries, and instead of using conditional formatting to either change the color or trigger a VBA function, I simply set the value of the field to either "" or the unicode character U+26A0 which is a warning symbol very similar to the image I was hoping to use.

The following script runs whenever the checklist is updated and causes a warning icon to be displayed or not to display as appropriate:

```
Private Sub OK_Click()

    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    
    SetRecord rs, "ApplicationContacts", , CurrentContact, "ID"
    
    If UniqueEmail And PhoneNumPresent And DOBPresent And AddressResidential Then
        
        rs.Edit
        rs![ContactWarning] = ""
        rs.Update
                
    Else
        
        rs.Edit
        rs![ContactWarning] = ChrW(&H26A0)
        rs.Update
        
    End If
    
    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    
    'Close checklist and save changes
    DoCmd.Close
        
End Sub
```

Many thanks to June7 for getting me pointed in the right direction!

Comment: I expect an IIf() expression in UNBOUND textbox could accomplish this without VBA populating field.

Comment: @June7 I think I see what you are saying, and I like the possibility of removing the ContactWarning field from the ApplicationContacts table. Are you thinking an expression like the following or am I missing something?
`=IIf(([DocGatheringContacts]![UniqueEmail]=True And [DocGatheringContacts]![PhoneNumPresent]=True And [DocGatheringContacts]![DOBPresent]=True And [DocGatheringContacts]![AddressResidential]=True), ChrW(&H26A0), "")`

Comment: Yes, that would be the idea. The `=True` isn't even needed. Nor is the extra pair of parens.

Comment: Right, I always space that. Thank you kindly!